# Q: How do I save variables for each user replie in a text file?

Tags: python, json, discord.py

Since we are soon coming back school I am adding an option to my discord bot where It will DM each user his zoom link based on day of the week, hour, subject.
Since I need this information to be saved if the bot goes offline I need The data from each user to be saved independantly.
For example, I need it to be in a file so the bot can dm him in the time defined,
Like this: wabulu#xyxy sunday 13:00 math
and for the script to read it as user=x time=y subject=z
The user inputs the info like the following

```
!dm @wabulu Sunday 13:00 math
```

I save it with the following:

```
day = args[0]
time = args[1]
subject = args[2]
```

Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: This sounds like a simple question, but it's actually quite complex as not everyone's needs are the same and simple answers are usually wrong. You are wading into the deep waters of database design.

Comment: I belive a csv or json would suit their needs best, but if they prefer a txt, they can use it.

Comment: It's not the underlying technology, it's the "how to do that" part. For example, if the bot comes back online, how does it know if the user has been notified or not? How does it know which Sunday? How does it know which time zone? Does this table need a unique id so that records can be updated and deleted later on? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("name.txt","a") as f:
    f.write(day+" "+time+ " "+ subject)
```

This seems like a simple solution right? However, as @JDB still remebers Monica stated,"You are wading into the deep waters of database design." This can get quite complex, and a txt maybe not be the best fit for you.

```
with open("name.txt","r") as f:
    lines=f.readlines()
dayarr=[]
timearr=[] 
subjectarr=[] #storing the lines in arrays.
for element in lines:
    a=element.split()
    dayarr.append(a[0])
    timearr.append(a[1])
    subjectarr.append(a[2])
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be txt, thats just what came to mind, I have no idea how to work with json files, I have no problem to learn tho, How would I read each user day,time,subject independentaly in your example ?